# After certain number of logins, CentOS server hangs, closes all connections

Tags: centos, ssh, login

So I normally like to maintain a lot of connections to the server, but after a server reboot, at about the eighth concurrent session, the login fails (times out), and *every* session to the server freezes and times out.  I have manually set the maximum number of logins in '/etc/security/limits.conf` with

```
*           hard    maxlogins     36
```

which previously allowed me 36 logins.  Anyone know what's going on with the new behavior, and how can I eliminate it?

**Edit**: I created a second user, and when I hit the login threshold, *that* login is frozen and timed out as well!  Yet this does not seem to affect other users--just 'my' logins, which are related by originating from the same IP address, I guess.  What could be going on??  Nothing has changed client-side afaik since the reboot that started this.

Comment: Check memory usage when you still got a working login.

Comment: Check if this happens only over network or also with a console login (use a remote console). To exclude firewall settings (which could be on the system or even on a firewall in the path).

Comment: @GerardH.Pille Tons of RAM, 512GB, only 10% in use at the point of freezing (watched `htop` as I increased login count).

Comment: @A.B Hmm I don't understand these two options--after connecting to a VPN (which stays connected throughout), I make `ssh` connections until failure, e.g. `$ ssh matt@192.168.x.xx`.  I don't really have any other way to connect.

Comment: 512GB RAM.  Have you tried adding more?  LOL.  Two more things to check: disk space and the logs.  Has CentOS switched to systemd?

Comment: @GerardH.Pille yes, systemd is used in CentOS 7 and 8, but not in 6, which is end of life at the end of this month.

Comment: @GerardH.Pille Disk space is a little tight on the home partition, but still 2-3 GB available (and no reason to think this has changed since the reboot).  `systemd` is running.  What logs would you suggest I check?  My Linux level is perhaps 'intermediate beginner' or thereabouts.

Comment: I would check those logs most recently changed. "find /var/log -mmin -3" is your friend. But with systemd, no idea. That rhymes!

Comment: @GerardH.Pille Thanks for the `find ... -mmin` tip, didn't know about that.  None of the logs that had been modified in the relevant timeframe (sa10, cron, btmp) indicaeted anything abnormal unfortunately.

Comment: So, that leaves the dreaded systemd to check, but I'm out of my depth here.  A "journalctl -a --no-pager" perhaps?    And a  "limits -a",  perhaps?

Comment: @GerardH.Pille Another great suggestion there with `journalctl`, looking at that I see a lot of this: "imjournal: fopen() failed for path: '/var/lib/rsyslog/imjournal.state.tmp': No space left on device".  Don't know how this would be true--seems like a not-uncommon issue--tracking it down.

Comment: please check "ulimit -a" for your user, Although rsyslog shouldn't be bothered by your limits.

Comment: "No space": out of inodes?

Comment: @GerardH.Pille Didn't see anything restrictive in `ulimit`, no problem with inodes--/var/log was filling up, not clear if that was related or not.  (Seems like problem started before /var got full.)  :/